# AWS Redshift failed to make a valid plan when trying to run a complicated query

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I'm running a complicated query against a Redshift cluster in which there are 4 tables used with some of them have billions of rows, and I get the following error:

```
failed to make a valid plan
```

If I limit the data, the query will run successfully.

Comment: I've encountered numerous intermittent issues on Redshift over the last few years.  The only three options I found are to VACUUM, ANALYSE and/or to simplify the query.  As RedShift is quite fast at writing as well as reading, breaking a larger query into two smaller steps is often relatively straight forward.

Comment: "I'm running a complicated query against a Redshift" - my experience is that the more complex the query the more likely you are to run into issues like this on Redshift. You might find it better to break large monolithic queries into multiple smaller queries, storing the intermediate results in temporary tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-The Original query was an Oracle query which I've made some modifications on it, and data loaded in the tables in Redshift was also exported from Oracle.

-The query has a lot of JOINs and sub queries.

With those being said, going through the sub-queries one at a time, one of them didn't return any results, and that was the cause of this error in my case.

Fixing that particular sub-query and the main query accordingly, it worked successfully.